# Overwrite a jar while in use - Java

Tags: java

I have jar client that has an auto updater built in, when you open it if there is a new version it will download it. I made it so it downloads the new version to the same directory that the user is running the current one from so that it's easy for the end user.

The problem with this is that it can't overwrite itself because it's in use obviously. As of right now it downloads a new version and I have the version in the name so it downloads a new one with like v1.1 or v1.2 in the jar name.

This works but just seems to messy in my opinion, does anyone know of a way to make it so I can just always have the same file name? IE does anyone know of a way to overwrite a file that's in use, or a work around that will close the current and replace then reopen the new one?

Here is my downloader class - http://pastebin.com/KJdDndhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution to this problem is to not have 1 Jar file both manage itself as the application and the updater. Have a separate Jar for updating and your current one act as the application alone.

This seems to be similar to how many applications with auto updating works.

League of Legends has a separate updater that runs before the main application launches

Antivirus usually loads their signature files into memory and close their connection to them allowing them to overwrite those files.

Answer (score 1):

When a JRE executes a JAR file, it loads the classes it needs and then releases the JAR file. So you will be able to overwrite the JAR file even from the code within the JAR file.

I have implemented the same update mechanism and it works fine for me on Windows 7, Ubuntu and Mac OS.

But if it's not able to overwrite for you, then from your code you are probably using up some resource which it has to keep the lock on (I am not really sure what, it's just my guess).